# Change proxy and IP settings for a SSID in android

Tags: android, proxy, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I have to connect to a router from my android phone sometimes with proxy and IP settings and sometimes without them. So I decided to automate the whole process with an app.

I searched the android API documentation and found `updateNetwork(WifiConfiguration config)` method of `WifiManager` class which can do the job. But the problem is `WifiConfiguration` doesn't have any methods to set the proxy or IP settings.

Is there any method to do this. Moreover I just wanted to change those settings for single network SSID. I use Android 5.1 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work in 5.1. Please refer below page for full code.
https://gist.github.com/madeye/4352485

```
WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration(configuration);
config.ipAssignment = WifiConfiguration.IpAssignment.UNASSIGNED;
config.proxySettings = WifiConfiguration.ProxySettings.STATIC;
config.linkProperties.clear();

config.linkProperties.setHttpProxy(new ProxyProperties("127.0.0.1", port, ""));
manager.updateNetwork(config);
```

But for Android 6.0 You can only update network which you have created.

Comment: `WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration(configuration);` This statement is giving an error that it can not be applied. Even the documentation had only the default constructor not the parameterised one's.

Comment: @crgarridos: You can only delete/update network you added through your apk. Suppose you joined to one ssid from Phone UI wifi settings. Same wifi ssid you cannot update from your apk.

Comment: @ManiSankar: The example is for older versions. Please read latest docs for updated apis. something like this i remember- `WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();conf.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);`. Similar way you can set ipaddress.